# get all the text between two newline characters(\n) of a raw_text using python regex

Tags: python, regex, text-processing

So I have several examples of raw text in which I have to extract the characters after 'Terms'. The common pattern I see is after the word 'Terms' there is a '\n' and also at the end '\n' I want to extract all the characters(words, numbers, symbols) present between these to \n but after keyword 'Terms'.

Some examples of text are given below:

```
1) \nTERMS \nDirect deposit; Routing #256078514, acct. #160935\n\n'
2) \nTerms\nDue on receipt\nDue Date\n1/31/2021
3) \nTERMS: \nNET 30 DAYS\n
```

The code I have written is given below:

```
def get_term_regex(s):
    raw_text = s
    term_regex1 = r'(TERMS\s*\\n(.*?)\\n)'

    try:
        if ('TERMS' or 'Terms') in raw_text:
            
            pattern1 = re.search(term_regex1,raw_text)
            #print(pattern1)
            return pattern1
    except:
        pass
```

But I am not getting any output, as there is no match.

The expected output is:

```
1) Direct deposit; Routing #256078514, acct. #160935
2) Due on receipt
3) NET 30 DAYS
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please also post sample of expected output in your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Sure. It's edited now.

Comment: Thanks for editing. These \n are real new lines or these are literal \n characters present there?

Comment: those are real new lines

Comment: Uhm that is confusing. You are using both line breaks _and_ `\n`s in your input file. Also your regex seems to treat `\n` as a literal, _not_ a real new line.

Comment: True. I got the mistake I am doing. Still not able to figure out the solution though.

Comment: If you would allow all variations of terms `(?i)\nterms\b.*\n(\S.*)\n` https://regex101.com/r/cKgEOV/1 and get the value from group 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```py
import re

text = '''1) \nTERMS \nDirect deposit; Routing #256078514, acct. #160935\n\n'
2) \nTerms\nDue on receipt\nDue Date\n1/31/2021
3) \nTERMS: \nNET 30 DAYS\n''' # \n are real new lines

for m in re.finditer(r'(TERMS|Terms)\W*\n(.*?)\n', text):
    print(m.group(2))
```

1. Note that your regex could not deal with the third 'line' because there is a colon `:` after `TERMS`. So I replaced `\s` with `\W`.
2. `('TERMS' or 'Terms') in raw_text` might not be what you want. It does not raise a syntax error, but it is just the same as `'TERMS' in raw_text`; when python evaluates the parenthesis part, both `'TERMS'` and `'Terms'` are all *truthy*, and therefore python just takes the last truthy value, i.e., `'Terms'`. The result is, `TERMS` cannot be picked up by that part!

   So you might instead want someting like `('TERMS' in raw_text) or ('Terms' in raw_text)`, although it is quite verbose.

Comment: I feel stupid. I almost had t right. It was the mistake with the wrong interpretation of \n.

Comment: How about 'Terms' or 'Terms' in raw_text:   ??? As I still have other keywords, and doing in the way you mentioned would be really long.

Comment: Try `if any(t in raw_text for t in ('TERMS', 'Terms')):`.